# The equation of tangent line to a level curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know how to find equation of tangent line a curve, but I don't consider how to show that a line passing through $P(x_{0},y_{0})$ and normal to a vector $\vec{N}=A\hat{i}+B\hat{j}$ has equation $$A(x-x_{0})+B(y-y_{0})=0.$$
I tried a lot but did not consider how to show this?

Comment: Hint: Say $P'=(x,y)$ is a point on that line. We have $\overrightarrow{PP'}\perp\overrightarrow{N}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a point $(x,y)$ belonging the the line. Then the vector $\vec X=(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ is parallel to the line. If $\vec N$ is normal to the line, then $\vec N\cdot\vec X=0$. That is, 
$$
A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)=0. 
$$